# Plus equal are separated

Tags: math-mode

I have the following inline code:

`$\texttt{TEST}(v *= 2, v += 2, v = 4)$`

But when it is rendered, the plus is very far away from the equal sign. How can I overcome this problem and make LaTeX consider += as a single operator?

[image: rendered]

Comment: Also, maybe you want to use some sort of code environment and font (fixed size) to insert code into your PDF's, instead of a math environment, such as `listings` (or `verbatim` if all else fails)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`+` is a binary operator and `=` is a binary relation. When TeX finds the sequence

```
v + = 2
```

it transforms it into

> **Ord**  **Bin**  **Rel**  **Ord**

but a **Bin** is not allowed before a **Rel**, so it's changed into an **Ord**.

Solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\pluseq}{\mathrel{+}=}
\newcommand{\asteq}{\mathrel{*}=}

\begin{document}

$\texttt{TEST}(v \asteq 2, v \pluseq 2, v = 4)$

\end{document}
```

or, manually,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\texttt{TEST}(v \mathrel{*}= 2, v \mathrel{+}= 2, v = 4)$

\end{document}
```

These exploit the fact that TeX doesn't insert any space between two consecutive **Rel** symbols.

[image]

You can also define a macro that switches the behavior, so you can type the formulas more naturally:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\switch}{%
  \mathcode`+=\numexpr\mathcode`+ + "1000\relax % turn + into a relation
  \mathcode`*=\numexpr\mathcode`* + "1000\relax
}

\begin{document}

$\switch\texttt{TEST}(v *= 2, v += 2, v = 4)$

$a+=b \quad \begingroup\switch a+=b\endgroup \quad a+=b$
\end{document}
```

I added a nonsense line to show that `\switch` respects grouping. The scope of `\switch` ends with the formula (or group) in which it's issued.

[image]

Comment: Very good explanation.

Comment: Can there be a libe break between two rel symbols?

Comment: @Aditya No, only after a relation symbol; consecutive ones are treated as a unit. Try `$\relpenalty-10000 a==b$\bye` and see; of course one could add a penalty in between to *explicitly* allow a line break.

Comment: Good. Curiously, the newcommand doesn't work for me. I had to type `\mathrel{+}=` inside my equations.

Comment: @erickrf Do you refer to `\newcommand{\pluseq}{\mathrel{+}=}`? Can you show an example of this failure? Maybe with a new question.

Comment: @egreg yes. I used amsmath, if it makes a difference. I will open a new question.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

```
$\texttt{TEST}(v \mathrel{{*}{=}} 2, v \mathrel{{+}{=}} 2, v = 4)$
```